# How to grab a specific <td> within a <tr> with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Trying to grab all the names of high schools from the **list of high schools in nyc** wiki page.

I've written enough of the script to get me *all* of the info contained within the `<tr>` tags of the table containing the list of high schools,   academic area and entrance criteria - but how can I narrow that down to what I thought would rest within `td[0]` (which spits back a `KeyError`) - just the name of the school?

Code I've written thus far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

NYC = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_high_schools_in_New_York_City'

html = urlopen(NYC)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'lxml')
schooltable = soup.find('table')
for td in schooltable:
    print(td)
```

Output I receive:

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="/wiki/The_Beacon_School" title="The Beacon School">The Beacon School</a></td>
    <td>Humanities &amp; interdisciplinary</td>
    <td>Academic record, interview</td>
</tr>
```

Output I'm *seeking*:

```
The Beacon School
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about you get the first `table` on the page, iterate over all rows, except the first header one, and get the first `td` element for every row. Works for me:

```
for row in soup.table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    print(row.td.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

I also managed to do this by looking for all the anchors inside `<td>` and then looking for title:

```
titles = next(
    i.get('title') for i in [
        td.find('a') for td in soup.findAll('td') if td.find('a') is not None
        ]
```